# Advanced sorting with few and one specific conditions

Tags: javascript

I've got an array like that:

```
    const teams = [
        { 
            name: 'team1',
            goalsScored: 10,
            goalsAgainst: 10,
            points: 7
        },
            name: 'team2',
            goalsScored: 12,
            goalsAgainst: 9,
            points: 6
        },
            name: 'team3',
            goalsScored: 5,
            goalsAgainst: 5,
            points: 4
        },
            name: 'team4',
            goalsScored: 3,
            goalsAgainst: 10,
            points: 0
        },
    ]
```

I would like to sort it like that: 
first condition: more points, if equal then
second condition: more goalsScored, if also equal then
third condition: less goalsAgainst.

This part is quite straight-forward. I did it like this:

```
    myGroup.sort((a, b) => 
            a.points === b.points && a.goalsScored!==b.goalsScored ? b.goalsScored-a.goalsScored :
            a.points === b.points && a.goalsScored===b.goalsScored ? a.goalsAgainst-b.goalsAgainst :            
            b.points-a.points 
        );
```

The forth condition is more difficult and that is what I'm struggeling with.

I've got an object to represent all games between players and results.

```
{
game1: [{ {rivals: ['team1', 'team2'], winner: "team2"} }],
game2: [{ {rivals: ['team1', 'team3'], winner: "team3"} }],
game3: [{ {rivals: ['team1', 'team4'], winner: "team4"} }],
game4: [{ {rivals: ['team2', 'team3'], winner: "team2"} }],
game5: [{ {rivals: ['team2', 'team4'], winner: "team4"} }],
game6: [{ {rivals: ['team3', 'team4'], winner: "none"} }],
}
```

So if all conditions above are fullfilled (equality on points, goalsScored and goalsAgainst) I need to check the equal teams and see which has won in direct game. The winner is higher in order then the team wchich looses.
If there is no winner (none) then we leave it as it is. 
This part of forth condition I can't resolve.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `compareGames` function:

```js
const compareGames = function (a,b) {
  for (var game in games) {
    var gameData = games[game][0];
    if (gameData.rivals.indexOf(a.name)>=0 &&
        gameData.rivals.indexOf(b.name)>=0) {
      return (gameData.winner == b.name)
    }
  }
  return false;
};

const games = {
  game1: [{rivals: ['team1', 'team2'], winner: "team2"}],
  game2: [{rivals: ['team1', 'team3'], winner: "team3"}],
  game3: [{rivals: ['team1', 'team4'], winner: "team4"}],
  game4: [{rivals: ['team2', 'team3'], winner: "team2"}],
  game5: [{rivals: ['team2', 'team4'], winner: "team4"}],
  game6: [{rivals: ['team3', 'team4'], winner: "none"}],
  game7: [{rivals: ['team5', 'team6'], winner: "team5"}]
};

const myGroup = [
    {
        name: 'team5',
        goalsScored: 9,
        goalsAgainst: 11,
        points: 8
    },{
        name: 'team6',
        goalsScored: 9,
        goalsAgainst: 11,
        points: 8
    },{
        name: 'team4',
        goalsScored: 9,
        goalsAgainst: 11,
        points: 9
    },{ 
        name: 'team1',
        goalsScored: 10,
        goalsAgainst: 10,
        points: 10
    },{
        name: 'team3',
        goalsScored: 9,
        goalsAgainst: 10,
        points: 9
    },{
        name: 'team2',
        goalsScored: 10,
        goalsAgainst: 10,
        points: 9
    }
];

myGroup.sort(function (a, b) { 
    //all the same
    return a.points === b.points && 
    a.goalsScored === b.goalsScored &&
    a.goalsAgainst === b.goalsAgainst ?
    compareGames(a,b) :
    //same points
    a.points === b.points && 
    a.goalsScored!==b.goalsScored ? 
    b.goalsScored-a.goalsScored : 
    //same points and goals
    a.points === b.points && 
    a.goalsScored===b.goalsScored ? 
    a.goalsAgainst-b.goalsAgainst :   
    //default
    b.points-a.points;
});

console.log(myGroup);
```